# Which way is up in a Borg cube?

Tags: star-trek, borg

Do we know which way up the drones stand relative to the outer hull on a cube? If the (presumably artificial) gravity goes toward the centre or the "walls", do we know what the experience of walking across an edge is?

Comment: the enemy's gate is down

Comment: @NKCampbell you beat me to it.

Comment: I’m not sure why this question is even asked.

Comment: @hamsandwich you could ask on scifistackexchange.stackexchange.com

Comment: I mean, why even ask? Out of the billion or so ships shown on Star Trek, have the individuals therein ever been "upside down"? Not even the Pakleds!

Comment: @HamSandwich So that, when you visit a Borg cube, the Borg don't laugh at you when you set up your ping pong table on the ceiling.

Comment: @MishaRosnach That brings up a couple of separate questions: the first is how the transporter operator (or the transporter itself) knows which way 'up' a person should be beamed onto another ship; the second being why ships travelling through interstellar space always meet in the same orientation. Maybe the second was a convention adopted to make the first easier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

As far as we've seen, the entire [cube](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Borg_cube) seems to have a single orientation. And there's no real reason to suspect otherwise. Virtually every other vessel in Star Trek uses a "one-directional up" configuration, thanks to artificial gravity. Thus, no need to walk around the edges.

Bonus: Here's an image from inside looking external, showing they are not oriented foot or head up relative to the exterior:
[image]

Comment: That interior screenshot is a viewscreen, though, not a window. As a projected image, it shows nothing about how the people inside are oriented relative to the outside of the cube. After all, no matter how your body is oriented, the viewscreen will be placed in front of your face for ergonomic reasons.